# Google maps not rendering on android phone ionic framework

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm having some issues showing a Google Map on my android phone.
This code works perfectly on google chrome but i get a white screen on the phone

Here's my HTML code:

`<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ion-content>
         <div id="map"></div>
     </ion-content>
 </body>`

And here's the javascript:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "My Location"
        });
    });

    $scope.map = map;
});
```

});

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in case someone has the same problem

You need tu use the API key provided by google
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

Get Key from google developer console.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<AIzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.......>&sensor=true">
```

Hmtl :

```
<div id="map-canvas"  data-tap-disabled="true"> 
            </div>
```

Add css :

```
#map {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.scroll {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Ref : 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/